# Defining the relationship between multiple term names in contextual filter

Tags: 7, taxonomy-terms, views

Content managers are supplying a comma separated list of taxonomy terms (apple,orange,banana) for a contextual filter (using Insert View).

We've got the patch from https://drupal.org/comment/7589873#comment-7589873 applied on views to allow content managers to provide multiple terms and convert them to tids.

We had tested prior to to content being added en masse, but now we are seeing results that are different from what we expected (and most certainly from what the results when we tested in November)

If the manager specifies apple - the view outputs nodes tagged with apple.
If the manager specifies orange - the view outputs nodes tagged with orange.
If the manager specifies apple,orange (or apple+orange) - the view outputs the nodes tagged with apple
If the manager specified orange, apple - the view outputs the nodes tagged with orange.

The query ends up including

WHERE (( (field_data_field_something.field_something_tid = '3903+3904' ) )AND(( (node.status = '1') AND (node.type IN  ('content_type')) )))

What we are expecting to see is:

If the manager specifies apple,orange - the view outputs all nodes that are tagged with apple OR orange.

Has anyone had any luck with this?